# How to provide value of $scope variable as string in HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Yeah, This is weird issue.

I am adding code to existing code base where there is a directive

```
<my-progress ng-progress="processingReport" msg="someString"></my-progress>
```

The problem is that `msg` needs to be dereferenced string.

I have a scope variable as `$scope.myStatus` but providing `msg={{myStatus}}` is not producing anything

Is there a way to dereference the value of `$scope.myStatus` so that `msg` only receives its value?

**UPDATE**

The directive looks like

```
.directive('myProgress', function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          var msg = attrs.msg?attrs.msg: "{{"+attrs.ngMsg+"}}";
            var template = '<p ng-if="'+ attrs.ngProgress +'"><img src="img/busy-20.gif" alt=""> '+ msg +'</p>';
            var el = $compile(template)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(el);
          }
      };
    })
```

**UPDATE 1**
As per **@charlietfl** recommendation, the following worked well

In Controller

```
$scope.runningStatus = {progressStatus: 'Not Started'};
```

In HTML

```
<my-progress ng-progress="processingReport" ng-msg="runningStatus.progressStatus"></my-progress>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the `myProgress` directive? It depends on the type of binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on directive code you should be able to use :

```
ng-msg="myStatus"
```

Which would get added into the template as an expression

Note the line in directive:

```
var msg = attrs.msg?attrs.msg: "{{"+attrs.ngMsg+"}}";
```

which looks for one or the other attribute and treats them differently

Comment: That works, just that the value is passed just once, if value for myStatus changes, it is never updated on the screen. I do not know how to solve this

Comment: try making your scope model an object with a property `myStatus` .... `$scope.someObj={myStatus:'som value'}` then `ng-msg="someObj.myStatus"`

Comment: Not sure if I followed you, but the way it looks is `   $scope.updateStatus = function(responsePayload) {
        var text = responsePayload.result['reportStatus'];
        $scope.progressStatus = text;
`. This is the first time `$scope.progressStatus` is used

Comment: always best to use objects on scope when you can ..instead of primitives

Answer (score 1):

The directive is kind of a hack and should be rewritten, but as is it should accept an interpolated expression:

```
<my-progress ng-progress="processingReport" msg="{{myStatus}}"></my-progress>
```

Don't forget the double quotes `"` around `{{myStatus}}`

If it still doesn't work, could you test that your scope is okay by adding this test element just after the directive one:

```
<div>{{myStatus}}</div>
```

Comment: That works, just that the value is passed just once, if value for `myStatus` changes, it is never updated on the screen. I do not know how to solve this